# Add local android support library to a gradle build without using SDK Deployer to add to mavenLocal

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, build.gradle

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add android support library to a gradle build, without using SDK Deployer to add the library to `mavenLocal`.  The main problem is how to configure the build to use the location on a local file system to resolve support library dependencies specified in the build file.

Comment: For the benefit of those searching for this stuff in the future: by "SDK Deployer", do you mean "SDK Manager", or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Downloaded using SDK Manager, but avoiding installing into a "mavenLocal" repository using SDK Deployer.  I'll edit the question to clarify. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out.  In case anyone else is trying to do the same, you need to add the local support library location to the gradle build `repositories` configuration in your build.gradle file, like so (substituting `path_to_sdk`, of course):

```
repositories {
    ... other repositories ...
    maven {
        url 'file://path_to_sdk/extras/android/m2repository'
    }
}
```